# Partitioning dataset into train, test and validate subset (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, partitioning

Im new to using Matlab and i'm trying to achieve the following situation:
I've one dataset of 7000+ entries. The goal is to train a classification tree (fitctree) on this data. I've seperated the data into a matrix with observations (predictors) and a matrix with classes(class). To partition the data i'm using cvpartition. Everything works fine up until this point.

Problem: I want to create three subsets with data: 1 training set, 1 validation set and 1 testing set. I want to train the tree using the training set, and validate its performance using the validation set. After tweeking the parameters I want to run the final test on the test data partition.
To partition the data I tried creating a cvpartition, which works, e.g.

```
cvpart = cvpartition(class, 'k', 10);
```

and then performing another cvpartition on that testing set, seperating this into another two sets:

```
cvpart2 = cvpartition(cvpart.TestSize, 'k', 10);
```

Sadly, when validating the performance of the tree this doesn't seem to work. When I skip the seond cvpartition, and validate the performance on the test set of cvpart, the model performs perfectly.

Update: after days I found that it seems to work when using it in this way:

```
cvpart2 = cvpartition(cvpart.TrainSize, 'k', 10);
```

Anyone care to explain me why it does work in this way, but not when using the test set?

Hope you guys can help me out;)
Kind regards.

Comment: `cvpartition` will split your data into `K` folds, then take `K-1` folds as train and 1 fold as test. And it will do this for all combinations of folds.
That means that in the first partition, `cvpart.train` will have 6300 elements and `cvpart.test` only 700 elements. You must use the train partition to partition again.

Comment: That's clear, but is the following true? 

The only reason performance is low is because it has to little data to correctly assess the model? Btw, Thanks for your prompt reaction BlackAdder!